# ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow's imageNet trained model to classify images in multiple categories.

I edited the script classify.py as

```
import tensorflow as tf
import sys
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

# Disable tensorflow compilation warnings
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
import tensorflow as tf

test_path = '/Users/kaustubhmundra/Desktop/Multi-Class Classifier/test'

classes = ['room','reception','washroom','facade']

result = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['facade','washroom','room','reception'])

def predict(image_path):
    #image_path = sys.argv[1]

    # Read the image_data
    image_data = tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_path, 'rb').read()

    # Loads label file, strips off carriage return
    label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line 
                       in tf.gfile.GFile("tf_files/retrained_labels.txt")]

    # Unpersists graph from file
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile("tf_files/retrained_graph.pb", 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # Feed the image_data as input to the graph and get first prediction
        softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

        predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
                 {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

        # print(predictions)

        pred = pd.DataFrame(predictions,columns = ['facade','washroom','room','reception'])

        # print(pred)

        global result

        result = result.append(pred)

        # print(result)

        # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
        top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

        for node_id in top_k:
            human_string = label_lines[node_id]
            score = predictions[0][node_id]
            print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))



path = os.path.join(test_path, '*')
files = sorted(glob.glob(path))

i=1

for fl in files:
    print(i)
    i = i + 1
    predict(fl)

result.to_csv('predictions.csv')
```

While I use it to predict on images, it works perfectly till 24 images but then shows an error :

> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 2154, in _as_graph_def
>       raise ValueError("GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.") ValueError: GraphDef cannot be larger than 2GB.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You're importing the graph every time you call predict(), and so you're accumulating a very large default graphdef. You should change your code so that you only load the graph once (the '# Unpersists graph from file' section), outside of your predict function. This should also speed up your code considerably.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
This works amazingly. This was pretty simple I don't know why it didn't strike me. :)

Comment: Having similar issue. How did you resolve it by loading your graph once?